# Stripe events for subscription and one time payment

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a custom code to execute for subscriptions and another one for one-time payments.
I have already written both codes and they are working fine. Now I would like to move each code to the right section where it must be executed. So I would like to ask you
if the `payment_intent.succeeded`  only fires when we have a one time payment and the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event  only fires  when we have a subscription ? If that's the case I will be able to place my codes when I capture those 2 events.

Comment: I found several other questions which all describe that subscriptions also trigger `payment_intent.succeeded`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462260/at-which-stripe-event-should-i-update-my-db-to-grant-subscriber-accessm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287698/how-can-i-handle-a-stripe-webhook-for-paymentintent-on-a-subscription-when-i-hav, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761604/which-webhooks-to-look-after-in-stripe-checkout ...

Comment: I tested and you're right. ANy idea on how to differ between these two cases ?

Comment: I have just checked your links and there are many suggestions out there ! thanks !